# Syntax error when trying to run my python program in virtualbox ubuntu with kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy

I'm using kivy to make a android app with python. I've set up virtualbox and installed kivy. When I use the following command `python3 main.py` I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ python3 main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/kivy/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-01-05_8.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc1, git-b1c643c, 20200105
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.3 (default, Nov 12 2018, 22:25:49) 
[GCC 4.8.4]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 953
     async def async_run(self, async_lib=None):
             ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: You are using Python 3.4 which does not support the `async def` syntax. Use a more recent Python version.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on an asynchronous function (`async def async_run`). This syntax was introduced in Python 3.5, but your VM has Python 3.4, which doesn't support this syntax.

The easy solution would be to upgrade Python on that VM to a newer version.

Comment: `async def` was introduced in Python [3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/).

Comment: @KlausD. indeed! I don't know where I got 3.7 from. I plead temporary insanity.